# How couild i load electron window in webpage?

Tags: javascript, electron

How to execute electron window and load that electron window into webpage to show how our application will look after build

Comment: Electron provides a way to run web components on desktop. So ideally you can just run your server and go to localhost

Answer (score 1):

As someone in the comment section mentioned electron just provides a way to run the web components on desktop. Therefore, If you want to see how the desktop app will look, just serve your javascript application directly on any port and open it just like any other web application.

Think of electron as an extra layer on top of your web application.